# How to use git via USB stick without a network connection to commit patches to a SVN repository

Tags: git, svn, version-control

I have **two networks** that are **not** connected. I can only use an USB stick to transfer data from one to the other.

On the **first network** there is a subversion control system. So I can checkout a working copy on computers on that network and also to an connected usb stick.

Also I can use git svn commands to create a git repository from subversion on the USB stick.

On the **second network** I can insert the usb stick on the first computer. But how to copy/push/pop the git repository from the usb stick to the first and the second computer on the second network and back to the usb stick ?

```
     PC A.1               PC A.2                                  PC B.1               PC B.2
   +--------+           +--------+                              +--------+           +--------+
   | SVN    |  Netw. A  | SVN    |                              |        |  Netw. B  |        |
   | Repos. |-----------| Working|===USB-Stick      USB-Stick===|  git ? |-----------| git ?  |
   | Server |           | Copy   |    git svn        git svn    |        |           |        |
   +--------+           +--------+       or            or       +--------+           +--------+
                                      svn wc         svn wc
```

Comment: This entire workflow sounds needlessly painful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git format-patch to be svn compatible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708202/git-format-patch-to-be-svn-compatible)

Comment: Yes it seems to be painful - but it's the only way by using a usb-stick

Comment: I was more hinting on the fact that I am scratching my head why you want to make it yourself so difficult by trying to use two different VCS like that.

Answer (score 0):

There are few protocols supported by `git` for eg. `ssh` protocol and `file` they are used as scheme in URI to [remote repositories](https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols)

You should add on USB stick some remote for eg. `origin` or any other meaningfull name through `ssh://user@comp1.net2/path/to/git/directory` like this:

```
git remote add origin ssh://user@comp1.net2/path/to/repo.git
```

Then you're able to `push` or `pull` from that repo which is on USB stick.
Adding another remote on USB stick with `file://` sheme gives you opportunity to `push`/`pull` changes when plugged to first network.

If you're not on Linux and have no SSH then you're going to need some other network transport protocol, for eg. `http` then you need to setup some HTTP Server which will serve your repository.